# mysql (phpmyadmin) Смена в столбце данных по условию

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

1) В строке 3 столбца: start, finish и status.

2) В столбце start хранится дата старта с типом datetime.

3) В столбце finish хранится дата окончания события с типом timestamp.

4) В столбце status хранится статус в типе text.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при совпадении реального времени с датой столбца finish, именно полное совпадение. То любой текст, какой бы не находился в столбце status, менялся на нужный? Например, если там было "Работает", то при совпадении автоматически поменяется на текст "Отключено".

Answer (score 1):

Сложно. Т.к. вызывать обновление придется каждую секунду... Как вариант можно сделать событие которое будет выполняться каждую секунду, но это глупо.

Лучше раз в N минут (опять же по событию event) обновлять все те у кого дата или только меньше текущей или between между текущей и предыдущей проверкой. Ну и желательно проверять статус.

Событие создается так:

```
CREATE EVENT `new_event`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
  ENABLE
  COMMENT ''  DO
UPDATE 
   table_name
set
  status = 'finished'
where
  finish between DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) and now() and
  status != 'finished'
;
```

Это создаст событие которое будет выполняться каждую минуту, и которое будет выставлять статус завершено всем строкам, у которых finish попадает в промежуток последних 2 минут (2 минуты, просто чтобы случайно из-за тормозов не пропустить какую-нибудь строку)

Естественно на finish не плохо бы повесить индекс.

P.s.: статус лучше сделать всё же enum-ом наверное, а не текстом...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET status='Отключено' WHERE finish = NOW()
```

Хотя, попасть в текущее время - нужно постараться, скорее всего тебе нужно:

```
... WHERE finish <= NOW()
```